dovecot-lda don't accept email from another user, how I do to fix?
Im trying to deliver email from a webform, but its not working.
I then tried manually in the console:
WORKS:
sudo -u info /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d info 

DOES NOT WORK:
sudo -u www-data /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d info 
sudo -u postfix /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d info 
sudo -u dovecot /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d info 

I need to be able to deliver email from "www-data" to any user on the system (that is a valid dovecot-lda mail user).
It seems a security setting blocks it. I have already set authdb to 0777 in dovecot settings, and also enabled stats-writer and stats-reader with 0666.
so no more error messages in log, but the above commands that does NOT work, terminate immediately, while the working command waits for email from STDIN. No error messages in either log or on STDOUT/STDERR.
